# Change multiple words in the string (JS)

Tags: javascript

JS function finds **a word** in the string and encodes it as "highlight".

But how can I change the multiple words to highlight instead of a single word?

For example;

```js
highlightWord('test#word#covid');
highlightWord('test');

function highlightWord(word) {
  var word = word.split('#');
  var string = 'Hello world, test text';
  var newWord = '<span class="highlight">' + word + '</span>';

  // do replacement with regular expression
  var allWords = new RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'gi');
  var newString = string.replace(allWords, newWord);

  console.log(newString)
};
```

Before:

```
hello world, this is a word1, word2 and word3
```

After:

```
hello world, <span class='highligh'>word1</span>, <span class='highligh'>word2</span> and <span class='highligh'>word3</span>
```

Comment: Do you mean a sentence or multiple words?  If the former realize you are using regular expression so `word1|word2|word3` would match either of those.  If the latter try pass in a sentence ('hello world').  In the general case you need to parse html, i.e. line breaks, and whatever tags might be inline, &nbsp; etc.

Comment: Hi Allan, I see but every word I separate with a hash (#) is different. For example; "finance#getting#table#wall" like this @AllanWind

Comment: If you insist on # separate words as input, use word.replace('#', '|').  Try it and let me know what you get.   You might need a () around the regex.

Comment: Why you dont simply create an array `word = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]` and then loop it calling same function on each? `word.forEach(w=> highlightWord(w))`

Comment: Demo on the JSfiddle @AllanWind  https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/bcmxzdpk/

Comment: Hi @ikiK thank you for your method. Nice but this is how I take the words directly. Unfortunately, I have no chance to change it.

Comment: ReferenceError: usw is not defined

Comment: Then split it to create array: `word = 'word1#word2#word3'; words=word.split("#") ; words.forEach(w=> highlightWord(w))`

Comment: I got 3 separate printouts on the console, Where am I making a mistake.. @ikiK

Comment: How about you say what are you even trying to accomplish? It is not clear. You have some inner HTML and outside word variable, its confusing.

Comment: Yes youre right therefore I updated my question with example @ikiK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

```js
const highlightWord = s => s.split('#').map(s => `<span class="highlight">${s}</span>`);

console.log(highlightWord('test#word#covid'));
console.log(highlightWord('test'));
```

You've edited your question, I'll update my answer:

```js
var words = 'word1#word2#word3';
var string = 'hello world, this is a word1, word2 and word3';

words.split("#").map(w => {
  var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + w + '\\b', 'gi');
  string = string.replace(regex, `<span class="highlight">${w}</span>`);
});

console.log(string);
```

Comment: Thank you but Is this giving as an array?

Comment: @Editor Yes. You can replace words inside text simply looping through the array.

Comment: Your method is so nice but I guess that's my problem. I can't do the loop.

Comment: @Editor I've edited my answer. Just take a look.

Answer (score 0):

It will loop 3 times as it needs, and you are interested in end of the loop, last result.

If you remove `console.clear()` you will see progress on each loop.

In order to work, see that I declared `oldstring` outside of loop.

And no need to create `newstring`, just change the old one on each loop.

```js
let word = 'test#word#covid';
let oldstring = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;

words=word.split("#");
words.forEach(w => highlightWord(w))


function highlightWord(word) {

  var newWord = '<span class="highlight">' + word + '</span>';

  // do replacement with regular expression
   var allWords = new RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'gi');
   oldstring = oldstring.replace(allWords, newWord);
    console.clear()
    console.log(oldstring)
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=oldstring
};
```

```css
.highlight{
color:red}
```

```html
<div id="test">Hello world, test text, covid, word</div>
```